# Multiple domains/subdomains for subsidiaries and umbrella company presence?

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain, branding

Here is the scenario: We have our main company that provides training and have decided to expand that into 3 other subsidiaries providing training for different areas of the same industry. Further to that, a new logo and name has been registered as the top level that all four of these categories now come under.

ie.
company-"group">
subsid - original training one, training two, training three, training four.

My First question is, should we divide those 4 sub companies up with their own websites and domain or possibly subdomains? - or do neither and keep everything under one roof?

Then, if the answer is the latter, would it be best to keep the original training as the 'front of house' to the website rather than replace it with the 'group' name and logo? (domain would be able to stay the same without conflict)

I realise there is no definite answer and knowing the right outcome depends on many factors that I've not been able to share but any guidence on the subject would be really appreciated.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

I cant speak about whether it would be more beneficial to create 4 new websites or use subdomains, or just using folders, this would probally be better answered from a business perspective, are the 4 companies together or not?  How 'together' are they?  Do you want the repuatation from one to affect the others?

As far as keeping the original site or creating a new one, as long as you pass 301 redirects, it doesnt matter, the rank from the old one will jumpstart the new "group" domain.

The question is if you really want to pass on the reputation from the old site, or you want to be seen as a wholly new enterprise.